# How to dynamically alternate between a canvas background color and an image in JS?

Tags: javascript, css, webgl

I have a webGL program where I create lights in my scene stored in an array. When I call render, I'm trying to make the background be black when there are no lights in the array and have an image instead if there are lights in the array.
The code in question is below:

```
if(lights.length == 0) {
  canvas.style.background = "#000000 none";
} else {
  canvas.style.background = "#00000000 url('nebula.png')";
}
```

Right now, everything appears black when I start the program (which is correct since there are no initial lights present), but when I add a light, the background doesn't change to an image and continues to be black.

I have debugged my program and, as the next image shows, I can access both the if and else clauses:

[image]

```js
let lights = [];
let counter = 0;

function setup(shaders)
{   
    let canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    let aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);


    function resize_canvas(event)
    {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;
    }

    function render()
    {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

            if(lights.length == 0) {
                canvas.style.background = "#000000 none";
            } else {
                canvas.style.background = "#FF0000 none";
            }
            
            if(counter%2 == 0) {
              lights.push(0);
            } else {
              lights.pop();
            }
            
            counter++;
    }
}
setup();
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    /*display: flex;*/
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; /*  Disable scrollbars */
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>LightStudio</title>
        <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="128" height="128">
            Oops! Something went wrong!
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above snippet has a similar behaviour to my program, but here I simulate the adittion and removal of the lights every time I call render, supposed to change between blue and red, which it works. The code also works in my program. But when I change the else clause to "upload" my image, it doesn't work.

Update: when changing the code in a way so the image appears when there are no lights, the image appears when the program begins, as intended, and changes to black when adding a light. But when I try to remove the light, the screen stays black and the image doesn't appear anymore.

```
if(lights.length == 0) {
            console.log("if")
            canvas.style.background = "#00000000 url('nebula.jpg')"
        } else {
            console.log("else")
            canvas.style.background = "#000000 none";
        }
```

Comment: There is no inherent issue with the code in question. I'd speculate that this statement isn't being processed with each render. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Are you sure the `else` block is even being invoked?  Add some logging (`console.log`) to verify.  Also you should provide more code and/or debugging details such as "I'm sure the `else` block was invoked".

Comment: @George tried to simulate my code in a snippet, should be available

Comment: @user2740650 have added clarification and a screenshot that shows my debugging, adding and removing a light

Comment: Try changing `"#000000 none"` to some other colour, eg. blue.  If it stays black, that would show that it's not being applied.  I'd guess that WebGL would override any background since it renders the entire rectangle.

Comment: @user2740650 yes, both in my snippet and in my program the screen stays black when there are no lights. Why is that? Shouldn't it be painting the background blue?

Comment: @Kob you aren't providing anything to `.push` to your lights array. If you do that, it seems to work as expected (the background changes with every available animation frame): https://jsfiddle.net/jm1k50bq/

Comment: Here's what I think happened: the snippet didn't represent the original problem, but I think the original problem was trying to use HTML style (background) when rendering with WebGL.  With WebGL, the WebGL code is 100% responsible for what is visible in the rectangle.

Comment: @George nice catch, forgot to push something. With colors it works, but when I try to add the image instead, it just doens't.

Comment: @user2740650 the thing is that it works when using changing the background colors, but not the image itself, I can't understand why.

Comment: OK so in your original code, you can change the colour from red to blue depending on whether there are lights, right?  If you just use the image background **without WebGL** does it show up?  If not maybe the image isn't loading.

Comment: @user2740650 what do you mean without webGL? But I've updated my question with an interaction (when changing the order so as the image appears when there are no lights instead) where the image initially appears, but doesn't reappear when removing a light.

Comment: @Kob it works here with a placeholder image: https://jsfiddle.net/ktaLyh3m/. I'd guess your image is not reachable. Check your network tab for the response status of the image.

Comment: "without webGL" means disable any WebGL code that is rendering to the canvas.  Like @George, I'm wondering if it's just a missing image or something.  But you said that you did see the image if you swap the if/else so that's not it.

Comment: @George I get 200

Comment: @user2740650 I disabled the objects I draw to the scene using webGL, the background still stays black